# Is it possible to define custom keyboard shortcuts with pcmanfm?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, file-management

I have seen how to add custom actions to the contextual menu by adding text files to ~/.local/share/file-manager/actions/. 
But I would like to link those actions to a keyboard shortcut, to use them without the mouse.

I have seen that this was possible with thunar, by editing ~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm.
Is something similar possible with pcmanfm ?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I'm using spacefm, a fork of pcmanfm that allows to easily add keyboard shortcuts.